# Pry commands - self, save

Tags: save, self, pry

I'm working on an exercise that is asking me to use pry to cd to a post I initially created in a rails console, and then to use self and save! to change the title of this post. I don't see either of these listed under the pry help commands, so I'm stuck.

Here is the display:

```
[13] pry(#<Post>):1> Post.first                                                                                                                                                               
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"   ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1                                                                                                       
=> #<Post id: 1, title: "First Post", body: "This is the first post in our system", created_at: "2015-05-05 03:55:22", updated_at: "2015-05-05 03:55:22">
```

Answer (score 2):

Pry is an enhanced alternative to the IRB shell for Ruby. This means you can also run Ruby within a Pry session. In this context, `self` refers to a keyword in Ruby and `save!` refers to a Ruby method.

To change the title of your post and save it, it would look something like this:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.6)
[1] pry(main)> Post.first
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"   ORDER BY "posts"."id"       ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Post id: 1, title: "My first post", body: "This is the first post!",   created_at: "2015-05-14 20:47:49", updated_at: "2015-05-14 21:42:02">
[2] pry(main)> cd Post.first
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"   ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
[3] pry(#<Post>):1> self.update title: "My new title"
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.3ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET "title" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE   "posts"."id" = 1  [["title", "My new title"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-14   21:42:36.731568"]]
   (2.9ms)  commit transaction
=> true
[4] pry(#<Post>):1> Post.first.save!
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"   ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
=> true
[5] pry(#<Post>):1> Post.first
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"   ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Post id: 1, title: "My new title", body: "This is the first post!",     created_at: "2015-05-14 20:47:49", updated_at: "2015-05-14 21:42:36">
[6] pry(#<Post>):1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure how to use "save!" in this case because strings do not have that method. I managed to change the title by using this:

self.update :title => "Changing post"